# Is there a performance difference between modeling a complete scene in Unity with assets vs importing a complete 3D scene from SketchUp?

Tags: unity, 3d, models, sketchup

I've worked with 3D modeling (architectural projects) using SketchUp for 4 years. I'm trying to import the models into Unity and then add the components I want (like colliders, scripts interacting with triggers and animations),

I wanted to know if it's feasible for me to make the entire game scenario (streets, houses, etc.) in SketchUp, reducing the number of polygons as much as possible, and importing the complete model into Unity.

In models that needed separate, like a house that the player would enter, where the collider would be different and not unique with every model, I would import to Unity separately.

Will the game's performance be affected if I only use the assets and assemble the scenario in Unity? Or will it only interfere with the game's storage, if I import the entire scenario, that is, more real data to my game folder?

It's a hell of a job to do everything in SketchUp, having to make groups in the entire scenario and set it up in Unity.

Comment: The best way to answer any question of the form "Is there a performance difference between A and B" is to make a very quick version of A and B and measure them. That doesn't need to include making a lot of final-quality content. If you just want to stress test the engine, grab whatever models you have handy and throw them in a scene until it's in the ballpark of the density you expect you need in your game. Use the profiler to see if there's a problem with your preferred workflow, and if so, post a question here specific to that problem and ask for solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. I will make a prototype and analyze. If there is any doubt in the execution, post it here. Tks! ;)